# Angular Routing: Just to change some variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I want to use routing in my Angular app, but I don't want to utilize any secondary controllers or templates. Is there a way I can use routes as a simple trigger to change variables (which in turn display different UI elements)?

Comment: Why even use routes, just use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` then set the variables...

Comment: Because I'd like users to be able to use the browser's navigation buttons and share links to particular application states.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ui-router, you can use $stateParams or if you are using ng-router you can use $routeParams. However, you still need to attach these values to the scope somewhere in order to bind them to the DOM.

Ex. 
Define your route with a parameter

```
.state('home', {
    url:/home/{param1}, 
    controller: SomeCtrl
}
```

http://example.com/home/ex1

In your controller, you can then inject $stateParams and access that parameter:

```
$scope.urlParam = $stateParams.param1;
```

Then you can bind urlParam to the DOM:

```
<div>{{urlParam}}</div>
```

The above example is with ui-router, if you are using ng-router, its very similar but you may want to take a look at the docs for syntax, etc.